# Is there a way to detect what type of shell os.system uses?

Tags: python, shell, cross-platform, system-calls, platform

How do you detect what shell `os.system` will call?

I am not sure if `os.name` or `sys.platform` will work, since the system might be configured to use a non-standard shell, like cygwin's shell on windows.

If my script is to run on windows and linux, I need to know the shell the system is using to know what syntax build commands with

Comment: If I got your question right, maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1492667/5386668

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: can you tell the name of the calling shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492508/python-can-you-tell-the-name-of-the-calling-shell)

Comment: @GurupadHegde I am not sure it is a duplicate of that question, since that question asks how to retrieve the parent-shell of a script from within the script, this question asks how to find what shell is being called when it executes os.system(), so how to find the child-shell

Answer (score 0):

The [os.system(*command*) docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) state (summarized & accentuated by me):

> **Execute the command (a string) in a subshell. This is implemented by
>   calling the Standard C function system()**, and has the same
>   limitations.

**WINDOWS**:

For windows, we can read this from the mentioned os.system() docs:

> On Windows, the return value is that returned by the system shell
>   after running command. **The shell is given by the Windows environment
>   variable COMSPEC**: it is usually cmd.exe, which returns the exit status
>   of the command run; on systems using a non-native shell, consult your
>   shell documentation.

**UNIX**:

For Unix, the mentioned os.system() docs read:

> On Unix, the return value is the exit status of the process encoded in
>   the format specified for wait(). Note that POSIX does not specify the
>   **meaning of the return value of the C system() function**.

And the [Linux docs](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system) appear to state that regarding the mentioned C function:

> **system()** executes a command specified in command **by calling /bin/sh -c** command, and returns after the command has been
>   completed.

So, I guess it save to say that on most (though not necessarily all) Unix system a os.system() call from python will be executed via a [Bourne shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell) command, c.q. `/bin/sh -c`.